# Compiling driver from Github Error

Tags: wifi, drivers, compiling, kali-linux, github

I'm currently trying to follow a set of instructions to download a wifi driver for a Cube i7. To do this, I set up a virtual machine with internet access and proceeded to complete these steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu.git
cd /rtl8723bu/ #direct to folder
sudo make
```

These are the steps I'm following to make the .ko driver file - but I'm honestly unsure if these are remotely correct as I'm just setting up Kali for the first time and trying to fix the wifi.

The sudo make command returns an error:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.3.0-kali1-amd64/build M=/root/rtl8723bu/rtl8723BU_WiFi_linux_v4.3.6.11_12942.20141204_BTCOEX20140507-4E40  modules
```

make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.3.0-kali1-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:365: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2

Any advice or guidance for how to compile that .git file would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know Kali, but it looks like you don't have the necessary kernel headers installed - FWIW on Ubuntu, they would be provided by the `linux-headers-generic` package

Comment: @steeldriver I thought that could be the issue - because even though I've updated the sources.list file, apt-get update and upgraded - I can't actually run that command to update the headers without getting a package not found error. Really don't know where I've gone wrong :(

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you running `make` with `sudo`?  And god, that repository has some of the worse documentations I have ever seen.

Comment: @grochmal To be honest I never have run it with sudo before, I was just following a guide on another forum so was trying to follow each step word for word. And I know with the documentation, it's the reason why I'm looking for any guidance on here!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with kali-rolling, make sure you have building requirement:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc make linux-headers-4.7.0-kali1-all
make
sudo make install
reboot
```

After reboot make sure it works with `iwconfig`, you should see something like:

`wlan1     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"`